# How to use multithreading with tkinter in this program

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

This code accepts user input as audio and responds accordingly and I want to use tkinter to display the conversation. I tried using using multithreading but it won't work.Please help me regarding how to use multithreading here.
Expected result :

1. The code should print the conversation on a window
2. And also listen to the user simultaneously

Here is my code

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

root = Tk()

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
# print(voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
    t = Text(root)
    t.grid(row=0, column=0,
       columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    t.insert(END, 'Genos says: ' + audio + '\n')


def wishme():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        speak("Good Morning sir")

    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        speak("Good Afternoon sir")

    else:
        speak("Good Evening sir")
    speak("I am Genos. How can I Serve you?")
    return
    t = Text(root)
    t.grid(row=0, column=0,
       columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    t.insert(END, 'Genos says: ' + wishme() + '\n')


def takecommand():
    # it takes mic input from the user and return string output
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing..")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user Said :{query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

        speak("Say that again please")
        return "None"
    t1 = Text(root)
    t1.grid(row=0, column=2,
        columnspan=2, rowspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)
    t1.insert(END, 'user says: ' + query + '\n')
    return query


def sendEmail(to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('mail@gmail.com', '###')
    server.sendmail('mail@gmail.com', to, content)
    server.close()
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":

    wishme()

    # while True:
    for _ in range(10):
        query = takecommand().lower()

        # Logic for executing task based query
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            speak('searching Wikipedia....')
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=5)
            speak("According to wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in query:
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif 'open stackoverflow' in query:
            webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")

        elif 'play music' in query:
            music_dir = 'D:\\SAHIL\\$ONGS_MJ'
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)
            print(songs)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))

        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            speak(f"Sir the time is {strTime}")

        elif 'open code' in query:
            codepath = "C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code 
Insiders\\Code - Insiders.exe"
            os.startfile(codepath)

        elif 'email to sahil' in query:
            try:
                speak("What should i say ?")
                content = takecommand()
                to = "mail@gmail.com@gmail.com"
                sendEmail(to, content)
                speak("Email has been sent")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                speak("Could nott send the email ")

        elif 'open mailbox' in query:
            webbrowser.open("gmail.com");

        elif 'how are you' in query:
            speak("I am fine sir. How are you?")
            continue

        elif 'i am fine' in query:
            speak("that's good to know, how can I help you")
            continue

        elif 'goodbye' in query:
            speak("bye Sir")
            exit()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you could run `pyttsx3` and `speech_recognition` in separated thread and it could use `queue` to send data to main thread which would have to run GUI. And in GUI you can use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` to check periodically if there is new message in queue and display it in GUI.

Comment: should I create a new function for GUI or use root.after(milliseconds, function_name) in if __name__ == "__main__":

Comment: you have to create function `def function_name()` to use it with `after`.  And you have to use it before `root.mainloop()` to run `function_name` first time, and you have to use it also at the end of `function_name` to run this function again and again - like in loop but without blocking `root.mainloop()` - because one `after()` can execute function only once (it doesn't repeate it periodically - so you have to use it many times).

Comment: BTW: example which uses `after` to update clock in `Label` every 1000ms: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/timer-using-after](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: BTW: you should create `Text()` only once - after `root = tk.Tk()` - and later you should only insert new strings in this `Text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't test speech recognition but at least it displays text which it speeks.

I put all your loop in function and run in `Thread`. I also send queue to this thread soit can send text (or commands like `\quit`) to main thread which use `after` to periodically (200ms) get text from queue and display in `Text`

```
import os
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import smtplib
import time

import threading
import queue
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishme(queue):
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().hour

    if 0 <= hour < 12:
        text = "Good Morning sir"
    elif 12 <= hour < 18:
        text = "Good Afternoon sir"
    else:
        text = "Good Evening sir"

    queue.put(f'{text}.')
    speak(text)

    queue.put("I am Genos. How can I Serve you?\n")
    speak("I am Genos. How can I Serve you?")


def takecommand():
    # it takes mic input from the user and return string output
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing..")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"user Said :{query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

        speak("Say that again please")
        return "None"

    return query


def sendEmail(to, content):
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login('mail@gmail.com', '###')
    server.sendmail('mail@gmail.com', to, content)
    server.close()
    return


def my_loop(queue):
    wishme(queue)

    while True:
        query = takecommand().lower()

        # Logic for executing task based query
        if 'wikipedia' in query:
            queue.put('searching Wikipedia....')
            speak('searching Wikipedia....')

            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=5)

            queue.put("According to wikipedia" + str(results))

            speak("According to wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif 'open youtube' in query:
            queue.put("opening youtube.com")
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif 'open google' in query:
            queue.put("opening google.com")
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif 'open stackoverflow' in query:
            queue.put("opening stackoverflow.com")
            webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")

        elif 'open mailbox' in query:
            webbrowser.open("gmail.com");


        elif 'play music' in query:
            music_dir = 'D:\\SAHIL\\$ONGS_MJ'
            songs = os.listdir(music_dir)

            queue.put(f"playing music {songs[0]}")

            print(songs)
            os.startfile(os.path.join(music_dir, songs[0]))

        elif 'the time' in query:
            strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            speak(f"Sir the time is {strTime}", queue)

        elif 'open code' in query:
            codepath = "C:\\Users\\Sahil\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code Insiders\\Code - Insiders.exe"

            queue.put(f"opening code {codepath}")

            os.startfile(codepath)

        elif 'email to sahil' in query:
            try:
                queue.put("What should i say ?")
                speak("What should i say ?")

                content = takecommand()
                to = "mail@gmail.com@gmail.com"
                sendEmail(to, content)

                queue.put(f"Email has been sent: {content}")
                speak("Email has been sent")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                queue.put(f"Could nott send the email: {e}")
                speak("Could nott send the email ")

        elif 'how are you' in query:
            queue.put("I am fine sir. How are you?")
            speak("I am fine sir. How are you?")

        elif 'i am fine' in query:
            queue.put("that's good to know, how can I help you")
            speak("that's good to know, how can I help you")

        elif 'goodbye' in query:
            queue.put("bye Sir")
            speak("bye Sir")
            queue.put("\quit")
            break # exit loop and thread will end                      
            #exit()

def update_text():
    if not queue.empty():
        text = queue.get()
        if text == '\quit':
            root.destroy() # close window and stop `root.mainloop()`
            return # don't run `after` again           
        else:
            t.insert('end', text)

    root.after(200, update_text)

# --- main ---

if __name__ == "__main__":

    engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5') # Windows
    #engine = pyttsx3.init('espeak') # Linux
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    # print(voices[0].id)
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

    # --- 

    root = tk.Tk()

    t = tk.Text()
    t.pack()

    queue = queue.Queue()

    update_text()

    task = threading.Thread(target=my_loop, args=(queue,)) # it has to be `,` in `(queue,)` to create tuple with one value
    task.start() # start thread

    root.mainloop()

    task.join() # wait for end of thread
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thanks for help.I tried doing it by myself but it won't do any good so I posted this on stackoverflow. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made this program into a .exe file and integrated it into another program the program works fine but when I run this program it gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'. can you tell me why is this happening